# How to know when StreamReader is ready?

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, python-asyncio

I'm using `asyncio` to make TCP connections:

```
reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(addr)
```

I need to keep connections alive. For this, I'm storing a pair of `(reader, writer)` for future communications. However, I don't know when `reader` has data to read. What can I do with it? Is there a way to make a handler, when the reader is ready?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I don't know when `reader` has data to read. What can I do with it?

The obvious way to know when a reader stream has data to read is to `await` it:

```
data = await reader.read(1024)
```

This will either return the data right away, or *suspend* the current coroutine, allowing other coroutines to make progress, and only resuming this one when the reader has some data to read. Instead of storing the reader/writer for future communication, you can write a coroutine that *does* the communication, and store the [task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task) that drives it:

```
async def communicate():
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(addr)
    # an echo server
    while True:
        line = await reader.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        writer.write(line)
        await writer.drain()  # backpressure, see https://tinyurl.com./hqylfay

task = loop.create_task(communicate())
# the task can itself be awaited, canceled, etc.
```

The idea behind the asyncio [stream API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html) is to write such sequential-looking code, leaving it to asyncio to handle polling of file descriptors and scheduling of tasks. You can use combinators like [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=gather#asyncio.gather) and [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=gather#asyncio.wait) to run thousands of such lightweight coroutines in parallel.

> Is there a way to make a handler, when the reader is ready?

If you need a callback-based API, you should probably use the lower-level [transports and protocols](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html) instead. However, if you are already working with streams, but still occasionally need an ordinary callback, you can get it by obtaining a [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future):

```
future = asyncio.ensure_future(reader.read(1024))
future.add_done_callback(your_callback)
```

Future has the role equivalent to a coroutine handler. Once [`read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamReader.read) would no longer block, the done-callback will be invoked by the event loop with a single argument, the future. The future will have finished, and its [`result()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future.result) method can be used to retrieve the received data or an exception.

(The above applies to any coroutine or future-compatible object in asyncio, not just to [`StreamReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamReader) methods.)