# What is the use case for future.add_done_callback()?

Tags: python-asyncio

I understand how to add a callback method to a future and have it called when the future is done.  But why is this helpful when you can already call functions from inside coroutines?

Callback version:

```
def bar(future):
    # do stuff using future.result()
    ...

async def foo(future):
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    future.set_result(1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = loop.create_future()
future.add_done_callback(bar)
loop.run_until_complete(foo(future))
```

Alternative:

```
async def foo():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    bar(1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(foo())
```

When would the second version not be available/suitable?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the code as shown, there is no reason to use an explicit future and `add_done_callback`, you could always `await`. A more realistic use case is if the situation were reversed, if `bar()` spawned `foo()` and needed access to its result:

```py
def bar():
    fut = asyncio.create_task(foo())
    def when_finished(_fut):
        print("foo returned", fut.result())
    fut.add_done_callback(when_finished)
```

If this reminds you of "callback hell", you are on the right track - `Future.add_done_callback` is a rough equivalent of the `then` operator of pre-async/await JavaScript promises. (Details differ because `then()` is a combinator that returns another promise, but the basic idea is the same.)

A large part of asyncio is **implemented** in this style, using non-async functions that orchestrate async futures. That basic layer of transports and protocols feels like a modernized version of Twisted, with the coroutines and streams implemented as a separate layer on top of it, a higher-level sugar. Application code written using the basic toolset looks [like this](https://vorpus.org/blog/some-thoughts-on-asynchronous-api-design-in-a-post-asyncawait-world/#example-1-asyncio-with-callbacks).

Even when working with non-coroutine callbacks, there is rarely a good *reason* to use `add_done_callback`, other than inertia or copy-paste. For example, the above function could be trivially transformed to use `await`:

```py
def bar():
    async def coro():
        ret = await foo()
        print("foo returned", ret)
    asyncio.create_task(coro())
```

This is more readable than the original, and much *much* easier to adapt to more complex awaiting scenarios. It is [similarly easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52140159/1600898) to plug coroutines into the lower-level asyncio plumbing.

So, what then *are* the use cases when one needs to use the `Future` API and `add_done_callback`? I can think of several:

- Writing [new combinators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51403277/1600898).
- Connecting coroutines code with code written in the more traditional callback style, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49351069/1600898) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50241573/1600898).
- Writing Python/C code where `async def` is not readily available.

To illustrate the first point, consider how you would *implement* a function like `asyncio.gather()`. It must allow the passed coroutines/futures to run and wait until *all* of them have finished. Here `add_done_callback` is a very convenient tool, allowing the function to request notification from *all* the futures without awaiting them in series. In its most basic form that ignores exception handling and various features, `gather()` could look like this:

```py
async def gather(*awaitables):
    futs = [asyncio.ensure_future(aw) for aw in awaitables]
    remaining = len(futs)
    finished = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_future()
    def fut_done(fut):
        nonlocal remaining
        remaining -= 1
        if not remaining:
            finished.set_result(None)  # wake up
    for fut in futs:
        fut.add_done_callback(fut_done)
    await finished
    # all awaitables done, we can return the results
    return tuple(f.result() for f in futs)
```

Even if you never use `add_done_callback`, it's a good tool to understand and know about for that rare situation where you actually need it.

Answer (score 1):

`add_done_callback` has an important use case that is often neglected: there must be a (strong) reference to a task, otherwise it may be garbage-collected before it is finished, so `add_done_callback` can be used with clean-up code that removes completed tasks from the container of tasks; cf. the documentation in https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html for `create_task`.